# Customize the prompts about opening documents in WebDAV Server Engine for .NET

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webdav, ithit-webdav-server

Is it possible to customize this dialog when a user clicks on a link to a document in WebDAV Server Engine for .NET?  E.g. Change the formatting etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dialog is part of a web browser and can not be customized. It is displayed when a protocol is triggered from a web browser. Every web browser provides its own dialog.